# Passing an additional field through a model form without adding it to the model

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to figure out how to add a field to a model form without adding the field to the model itself. I just need to pass in this extra field to the view it returns.

My django project has a page where the user uploads a text file which gets saved to the DB (the file upload form is the model form). It then returns a page where the important content from the text file is displayed. I want to add a dropdown on the same page as the file upload form that allows the user to select an option for how the content should be displayed when it returns the next page. I don't want this dropdown to be part of the model for the text file as I don't need to save it to the db. I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass this option into the view without adding it to the model itself.

Upload form:

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="text-upload-form">  
    {% csrf_token %}  
    {{ form.as_p }} 
        <label for="display-type">Display type</label>
        <select id="display-type" name="display-type" form="text-upload-form">
            <option value="highlighted">Highlighted display</option>
            <option value="dark">Dark display</option>
        </select>

    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>  
</form>
```

Views.py

```py
def parser(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        text_upload = TextFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if text_upload.is_valid():
            text_file = request.FILES
            handle_text_upload(request.FILES['file'])
            model_instance = text_upload.save()
            t = model_instance.file.path
            f = open(t, 'r')
            context ={
                't': t
            }
        return render(request, 'Parser/results.html', context)
    else:
        text_file_form = TextFileForm()
        return render(request, 'Parser/parser.html', {'form': text_file_form})
```

Model form

```py
class TextFile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TextFile
        fields = "__all__"
```

Is there a way to do this, or would it be better to just add the Display property to the model itself?

Comment: Override the forms init in the modelform

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by adding fields just before `class Meta` like this

```
class TextFile(forms.ModelForm):
    additionField = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = TextFile
        fields = "__all__"
```